# external usb mouse issues

Tags: usb, mouse, 18.10

I'm trying to work on a 18.10 ubuntu fresh installed cause in 18.04, my external usb mouse doesn't want to work perfectly, sudendly. Randomly, just pushs itself to a corner, and rests there. There is no visible pattern and I have the same behaviour, with the trackpad. And sudendly, goes back to normal control. I have a Toshiba Tecra R940-1GN.

Please help me cause I'm going crazy about this thing.

best regards

Comment: I don't think it has something to do with Ubuntu. It looks like a mouse hardware issue. I had such a mouse case and I later noticed that my mouse was broken

Comment: Maybe you're right. But I must close all the software doubts before go to the toshiba partner here in Portugal/Lisbon. Thanks.

Comment: I met that issue in Ubuntu 16.04, I was using the mouse for over a year, it started acting up after I dropped it down. The symptomps was just like  you described it above. Thinking twice, you may be right, it maybe related to mouse module of the Linux kernel.

Comment: Today I put it on Toshiba repair services. Hope it comes fine, cause I miss it already.

Comment: Hum, I hate to say it but it was an hardware problem, under the keyboard. Now it works perfectly. Thank you all